# EasyPhp and Netbeans - how configure project to run normaly the .php-s

Tags: php, netbeans, easyphp

I have the following problem: [screen image](http://imageshack.us/f/215/captureno.png/)

The NetBeans project configure to use the localhost `(http://127.0.0.1:8888/Php_alapok/)` but if **I want to only the Alapok.php file run in the browser** `(http://127.0.0.1:8888/Php_alapok/Alapok.php)`,however it not possible! *Because the browser always invites the index.php* or that page that you see on the screen image.
How can I aim that only the Alapok.php run in the browser, and don't the index.php?

I use the newest NetBeans IDE and EasyPhp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferred way will be to use **Run file** from **Run** menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> by default), same goes for debugging only current file.

You can also configure **Apache** to look for **Alapok.php** if no index.php was found. Do it by adding **Alapok.php** to the `DirectoryIndex` directive in **httpd.conf**. This way you should be able to execute Alapok.php when yuo press **Run project**. To debug project you should also set **Alapok.php** as **Index file** in NetBeans project configuration.